# The best way to run completely unrelated queries together?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I seem to be running into this issue often, usually for checking to see if a $_GET['id'] actually exists in my database before running another query, related or not to the id being received.

If a record exists with the same id, then I show the HTML, e.g.:

```
if ($r) { #query was successful
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    if ($num == 1) {
        ?>

        <form method="post">
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <?php
    } else {
        echo 'No records';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Query Failed';
}
mysqli_free_result($r);
```

The above works, but let's say that I want to perform another *unrelated* query between my opening/closing form tags; would it be proper to simply do something like this, which I would consider a nested query:

```
$q = "SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE id = $id";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
if ($r) { #query was successful
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    if ($num == 1) {
        ?>

        <form method="post">

        <?php
        $q = "SELECT example FROM somewhere";
        $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        if ($r) {
            $num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
            if ($num > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    echo $row['example'];
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Query failed';
        }
        ?>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <?php
    } else {
        echo 'No records';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Query Failed';
}
mysqli_free_result($r);
```

Or maybe create a boolean, like so:

```
$id_status = 0;

$q = "SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE id = $id";
$r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
if ($r) { #query was successful
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    if ($num == 1) {
        $id_status = 1;
    }
}
mysqli_free_result($r);

if ($id_status) { #Run another query
    ...
}
```

I currently have a problem when it comes to requiring two separate query results for one task: (1) generating inputs from another table, (2) displaying the current values, (3) checking to see what input that has been generated matches the current value, e.g.:

```
$q = "SELECT id, food FROM restaurants";
$q = "SELECT favFood FROM people WHERE id = 1"; #favFood is equal to the id of food
...
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    #generate all food from table, make favFood the current selected input
    <input type="radio" name="yum" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
    <?php
}
```

So as you can see, I am having trouble when it comes to unrelated queries; the last example would probably work with a UNION or something, but i'd have a bunch of repeated rows displaying favFood, so it doesn't feel right, e.g.:

```
favFood | id | food
    1   |  1 | Pizza
    1   |  2 | Burgers
    1   |  3 | Monkey Brains
```

Before I end this, I just want to say that I have made an attempt to use mysqli_multi_query, but I most likely did something wrong; i'm not even sure if it would work in this case, or what it does exactly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a record exists multiple times in your code, I suggest to create a function which returns a bool.

```
function record_exists($dbc, $q){
    $state = false;
    if($r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1){
            $state = true;
        }
        mysqli_free_result($r);
    }
    return $state;
}

$q = "SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE id = $id";
if(record_exists($dbc, $q)){
    echo 'Yay, it exists';
}
```

Then if you want to `SELECT` some fields from a table but the filter depends on a value from another table, you could `JOIN` two tables in the query like so:

```
SELECT restaurants.id, restaurants.food
FROM restaurants
JOIN people ON restaurants.id = people.favFood
WHERE people.id = 1
```

Now you only `SELECT` the fields you want from table restaurants and filter them on a person id from the table people.

Comment: For some strange reason it all works, granted, I have to call the function like so: if (!record_exists...), which has me stumped - it looks right, the connection is made when I use "!". I think it has something to do with the $state = false.

Comment: At the start of the function $state is set false, if the result num rows equals 1 then $state is set to true.

Comment: I agree that it makes sense, but once state is set to false, the rest of the function is being ignored, if ($r...) never happens.

Comment: I don't agree, i tested it with the following code: `function test($foo){ $state = false; if($foo == 'bar'){ $state = true; } return $state; } $test[1] = test('bar'); $test[2] = test('nope'); foreach($test as $result){ var_dump($result); } ` **Result:** `[1] boolean true; [2] boolean false;` This test has the same function as your `record_exists()` So if yours returns `boolean false`, either there was no result on the query or the result doesn't equal 1 row in total.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons why you've got such a problem

1. You are doing A LOT of useless stuff.

   - no one needs you "query failed" statement.
   - num rows check is also superfluous
   - most of the code you write is just *repetitions*
2. Like PHP users from the last century you are mixing database calls with HTML output. Now you see that the term "spaghetti code" was coined for a reason.

Your database related code rewritten with simple mysqli wrapper:

```
$rows = [];
$found = $db->getOne("SELECT id FROM stuff WHERE id = ?i", $id);
if ($found) {
    $rows = $db->getAll("SELECT example FROM somewhere");
}
```

Now you can proceed to HTML output, either inline or (better) by including a *template*

```
?>
<?php if ($rows): ?>
    <form method="post">
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
        <?=$row['example']?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php else: ?>
    No records
<?php endif ?>
```